# what happens to the messages in producer 'buffer.memory' if the producer app is crashed before they were sent to the broker?

Tags: spring-kafka

I am using spring-kafka 2.2.8 and writing a simple producer with the below settings:
linger.ms : 5
max.block.ms: 60000

Now my question is, what happens to the messages in producer 'buffer.memory' if the producer app is crashed before they were sent to the broker (especially in a asynchronous producer call mode)?

Is there any option to capture the status of these messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The records will be lost; you need to get the result of the `Future` for the send to ensure that they actually arrived at the broker.

Comment: Thanks for the response @Gary. I'm trying to override 'onSuccess' and 'onError' methods of ProducerListener and see if I can capture and track the producer record details but the problem is, if the producer app itself is crashing before getting control back to either these methods, we will lose those records and left with no details of the call.